# Python Selenium Copy Table Columns by Column Name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a table that has these headers, like this:[image: Table with Column Headings]

How would I select the whole column using xpath to store in an array.
I was hoping for different arrays, like:

```
courses = []
teacher = []
avg = []
```

Bare in mind these column don't have any ID's or classes, so I need a way to select just by using the name of the column.

Here is the code for the table:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">Courses</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">Teacher</td>
<td><select name="fldMarkingPeriod" onchange="switchMarkingPeriod(this.value);">
<option value="MP1">MP1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="MP2">MP2</option>
<option value="MP3">MP3</option>
</select>Avg</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">[Course Name]</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">[Teacher Name]</td>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td title="View Course Summary" width="70%">100%</td>
<td width="30%">A+</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">[Course Name]</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">[Teacher Name]</td>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td title="View Course Summary" width="70%">100%</td>
<td width="30%">A+</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">[Course Name]</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">[Teacher Name]</td>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td title="View Course Summary" width="70%">100%</td>
<td width="30%">A+</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Impossible to provide a good answer without having an HTML code of the table.

Comment: @alecxe here you go, but i did remove some personal and extra info, and also cleaned it up a bit. Hopefully this will help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly you need the data by columns, but here is a sample implementation:

```
courses = []
teachers = []
avgs = []

for row in table.find_elements_by_css("table > tbody > tr")[1:]:
    course, teacher, _, avg = [td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td")]

    courses.append(course)
    teachers.append(teacher)
    avgs.append(avg)
```

Comment: gave an error: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. It it the code?

Comment: I also changed the 4th line in your text to 'driver.find_elements_by_css_selector', but it still gave me the same error...

Comment: Sorry to respond so late, but still the same error... still don't know how to fix...